# Convert a variable to a string

Tags: theming

Using Drupal 8, I have a media field where someone can upload an SVG file.
I have this field display set to output as the URL path to the file.
I'm trying to get this value as a string (currently it's a render array) so I can call it with `{% include var %}` and embed the SVG directly into the DOM.

For example, I have this code. (I'm using [twig_field_value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value).)

```
{% set var = content.field_media_name|field_value %}
```

If I render the variable in the template with `{{ var }}`, it spits out a string onto the screen, for example /sites/default/files/pathto/file.svg.

If I manually copy-paste this string into my twig template, e.g. `{% include '/sites/default/files/pathto/file.svg'%}`, it works perfectly, just like I want. However, I want to use `{% include var %}`, which is causing a PHP error because it can't include a template file because the var is actually an array.

This field can only have a single value.
What I need is figuring out how to convert this into an actual string so I can use it with `include`.

Comment: You can access the string value of the array if you know the key which holds the value. You can figure that out by dumping the render array.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
{% include file_url(content.field_media_name|field_target_entity.field_file_upload.entity.uri.value) %}
```